# Same random record across website

Tags: django

I am building a website that shows a different background every time a user enters it. This background is then used across the website with the same user and session.

So basically, a user entres the homepage, gets a background and that image won't change until the user closes the website or opens up a new page. I think you understand what I mean.

I know how to get a random record from the database using Django, but I'm not sure how to keep that record persistent across the website, because if I pull it on every view, I'll get a different image on different pages.

So my "index" view could be calling

```
bgimage = BackgroundImage.objects.random()
```

But then I have a problem. How can I get this random record unchanged across all the other views. Is that possible? Should I be looking into sessions, cookies?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context processor:

```
def bgimage(request):
    if 'bg_image' not in request.session:
        image = BackgroundImage.objects.random()
        request.session['bg_image'] = image.file
    return {'background_image' : request.session['image']}
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel! I see what I was doing wrong. That solved it, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

you could use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) - something like

```
if 'bgimage' not in request.session:
    bgimage = BackgroundImage.objects.random()
    request.session['bgimage'] = bgimage.pathtoimage
```

Comment: you can use session on server-side, or you can save info about image in cookie and set proper css-class, or background property on client-side

Comment: Every view you needed the functionality for. You could also create a context processor if it's going to be on every view, so you don't have to repeat yourself.

Comment: as @chrisdpratt said put it in a context processor